# Transform numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to transform a numpy matrix (say '**Mat**') in the following manner:

```
Mat[i,j] = Mat[i,j] - numpy.sum(Mat[i,:]) * numpy.sum(Mat[:,j])
```

Given below is the code that I am using (two for loops). I was wondering if there is a faster method to implement this.

```
def Normalize(Mat):
    MargR = Mat.sum(axis=0)
    MargC = Mat.sum(axis=1)
    for i in range(len(Mat[:,0])):
        for j in range(len(Mat[0,:])):
            Mat[i,j] = Mat[i,j] - MargC[i]*MargR[j]
    return Mat
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second matrix you are multiplying is the outer product of summed rows and the summed columns, so you could write the new matrix as:

```
Mat = Mat - np.outer(np.sum(Mat, axis=1), np.sum(Mat, axis=0))
```

Comment: Awesome answer!!